# Can the 'software' application replace apt-get?

Tags: linux, debian

I found the application`software' is installed by default in Debian and Ubuntu.  I can also update and install packages in this application.   What's the aim of this application?  Can  it replace apt-get ?

Answer (score 2):

[Software](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Software) is GNOME’s software management tool. It supports a number of plugins which allow it to act as a frontend to a variety of systems: it can thus install `apt`-managed packages (*via* [PackageKit](https://wiki.gnome.org/PackageKit)), but also Flatpak applications, firmware updates…

As far as users are concerned, most of the time they can use only the Software application to install, upgrade and remove packages. (The main exception is for distribution release upgrades; some distributions allow those to be handled through Software, but that’s not universally true.)

It doesn’t replace `apt`, it relies on it in the background; but that’s just technical detail.